# How to mock Kotlin singleton function call in a java test with Mockito?

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito, junit5

Usually when I need to mock an static method I do something like:

```
 @Mock
 MockedStatic<AdOptions> adOptionsMockedStatic;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach(){
   adOptionsMockedStatic.when(() -> AdOptions.getFactory(any())).thenReturn(adOptionsFactoryMock);
}
```

I have in that project a Kotlin Singleton, that I access thru `InterstitialAdCallbackAndListeners.INSTANCE.method()`

I can not find a way to mock the method return, I tried this unsuccessfully

```
@Mock
        MockedStatic<InterstitialAdCallbackAndListeners> interstitialAdCallbackAndListenersMockedStatic;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach(){
   adOptionsMockedStatic.when(() -> AdOptions.getFactory(any())).thenReturn(adOptionsFactoryMock);
}
```

It does not trigger any build problem but crashes while running:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
> Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

Comment: Kotlin object functions are instance methods, not static methods, technically.  Although you really shouldn't ever mock static methods anyway.

Comment: When using/creating libraries there is no way around mock static methods, specially on Android :(